# Can we use ` to recognize when the asker post too much code in comments?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

I notice with new users when I ask something like "please post your controller code" they will almost always copy and paste it into a comment. Can there be a way to look for large chunks of code (say more than 20 characters)  in a the comments from a question's owner, and activate a warning similar to the "let's move this to chat" warning? So they would get a popover saying "It looks like you are putting a large amount of code into your comment, please edit your question or answer to include relevant code rather than putting it in the comments".

This could be something that only activates on users below a certain reputation threshold. That way instead of actually trying to capture code, it could just look for very long comments?

Comment: Can we? Sure. Should we?

Comment: Most often new users don't bother themselves to format the code, *especially* in comments, at least because it is not really clear how to.

Comment: Alternatively perhaps we could head that off by having some way to mark a question as needing code adding in the same way that duplicates now indicate that the question should be edited in order to reopen it.

Comment: Thank you robert-longson. That is the type of input I was looking for. SO needs a "Post more code" flag. Or maybe just a couple click-throughs that remind a user with less than 100 points to edit rather than comment, etc.

Comment: You should use the `[edit]` magic link to indicate they should put the code in an edit, such as "Can you please [edit] and add your controller code? I can't tell what the hell you're jibberjabbering on about. Just show me some code! Don't make me [edit] this myself!"

Comment: LOL! That's exactly what I want to do. Guess I can do that and STILL be polite. :-)

Comment: I guess another way to look at is, sometimes I see questions and I think "Who the f$%k reviewed this question and clicked 'looks good'?". Is the preferred response to just down-vote it? I try to only review questions where I have some clue of the technology being asked. i.e. Ruby, Rails, SQL, etc. If it's something out of my depth I just skip it. I handled a question recently that, seriously, every person who reviewed it was asleep at the wheel.